# im trying to make a discord.py prefix changer that saves in a database but it just wont work, also its not that neat

Tags: discord.py

i have been coding a discord.py bot i have been trying to code the prefix for my bot (using a database (postgresql)) the code went like:

```
`ORIGINAL_PREFIX = "&"

async def get_prefix(bot, message):
    if not message.guild:
        return commands.when_mentioned_or(ORIGINAL_PREFIX)(bot, message)

    guild_id = message.guild.id
    async with bot.db.acquire() as connection:
        prefix = await connection.fetchval('SELECT prefix FROM guilds WHERE "guild_id" = $1::bigint', guild_id)

        if prefix is None:
            async with bot.db.transaction():
                await connection.execute('INSERT INTO guilds("guild_id", prefix) VALUES ($1, $2)', guild_id,
                                         ORIGINAL_PREFIX)
                prefix = ORIGINAL_PREFIX
        return commands.when_mentioned_or(prefix)(bot, message)



bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=get_prefix)


async def created_db_pool():
    bot.db = await asyncpg.create_pool(database="...", user="postgres", password="blah blah")


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"[ Online and connected to Guilded. User: {bot.user}]")
    print('------')
    print('Guilds: ' + str(len(bot.guilds)))
    print('------')


@bot.command()
@commands.has_guild_permissions(manage_guild=True)
async def setprefix(ctx, new_prefix):
    guild_id = ctx.guild.id
    async with bot.db.acquire() as connection:
        await connection.execute('UPDATE guilds SET prefix = $1 WHERE "guild_id" = $2::text', new_prefix, guild_id)
    await ctx.send(f"Prefix changed to `{new_prefix}`")
`
```

hope someone reads this, thank you!

It wont work kept getting an error: Ignoring exception in on_message:
`Error: Ignoring exception in on_message:` Traceback (most recent call last):
File "asyncpg\protocol\prepared_stmt.pyx", line 175, in asyncpg.protocol.protocol.PreparedStatementState._encode_bind_msg
File "asyncpg\protocol\codecs/base.pyx", line 227, in asyncpg.protocol.protocol.Codec.encode
File "asyncpg\protocol\codecs/base.pyx", line 129, in asyncpg.protocol.protocol.Codec.encode_scalar
File "asyncpg\pgproto./codecs/int.pyx", line 105, in asyncpg.pgproto.pgproto.int8_encode
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "path_to_your_script", line 404, in _run_event
await coro(*args, **kwargs)
File "path_to_your_script", line 568, in on_message
await self.process_commands(message)
File "path_to_your_script", line 556, in process_commands
ctx = await self.get_context(message)
File "path_to_your_script", line 472, in get_context
prefix = await self.get_prefix(message)
File "path_to_your_script", line 447, in get_prefix
ret = await guilded.utils.maybe_coroutine(prefix, self, message)
File "path_to_your_script", line 313, in maybe_coroutine
return await value
File "path_to_your_script", line 15, in get_prefix
prefix = await connection.fetchval('SELECT prefix FROM guilds WHERE "guild_id" = $1::bigint', guild_id)
File "path_to_your_venv\Lib\site-packages\asyncpg\connection.py", line 715, in fetchval
data = await self._execute(query, args, 1, timeout)
File "path_to_your_venv\Lib\site-packages\asyncpg\connection.py", line 1794, in _execute
result, _ = await self.__execute(
File "path_to_your_venv\Lib\site-packages\asyncpg\connection.py", line 1892, in __execute
result, stmt = await self._do_execute(
File "path_to_your_venv\Lib\site-packages\asyncpg\connection.py", line 1945, in _do_execute
result = await executor(stmt, None)
File "asyncpg\protocol\protocol.pyx", line 186, in bind_execute
File "asyncpg\protocol\prepared_stmt.pyx", line 204, in asyncpg.protocol.protocol.PreparedStatementState._encode_bind_msg
asyncpg.exceptions.DataError: invalid input for query argument $1: 'jJ99444E' ('str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer) 
also its just not neat help